# Python - Method to get the array around an slice in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I define a Matrix NxN, with random values(0,1). I need to get the sum of the digits around the consecutive 1's.

For example:

```
100110001
101001000
100001001
000000000
000111001
000000100
.. ..
```

For 111  in the above, the sum of the surrounding digits is 1.

Is there some way using *numpy* or *itertools* or anything to get the sum or the array of the digits around??
Please help, cheers

For detecting random consecutives 1's i use:

```
from itertools import groupby

def groups(l): 
    return [sum(g) for i, g in groupby(l) if i == 1] 

con += list(filter(lambda x: x > 1,groups(matrix[4])))
```

And to get the index of 1s :

```py
idx+=[idx for idx, i in enumerate(matrix[4]) if i == 1]
```

Comment: Better to write a custom function for this. I don't believe there is a pre-built function just to calculate the 1s surrounded by 1s.

Comment: what about edge cases , for example if 111 is in the top row of the matrix? Also, are you counting consecutive 1s in both dimensions (e.g. do vertically consecutive 1s count)? Also, what if a combination of horizontal and vertical 1s appears in a connected group - what then ? Its hard to provide a solution without the answer to those questions.. Anyhow, I think you can use the scipy.ndimage library for this, some combination of binary dilation, and image labeling

Comment: No matter, if its at the first row 0001111000 just take both sides left and rigth of 1111 and the bottom row. If its at a corner or column[0] or row[n-1]  just take what you have, **the numbers adjacent a slice of consecutives 1s** @dermen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not fully answer your question, but it might point you in the right direction :

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy import ndimage as nd

In [3]: mat = np.random.randint(0,2,(6,6))

In [4]: mat
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [5]: s = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]])

In [6]: lab, nlab = nd.label(mat, s)

In [7]: lab
Out[7]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  0,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  0,  0,  4,  0],
       [ 5,  0,  6,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 0,  0,  7,  7,  7,  0],
       [ 8,  0,  9,  0, 10,  0],
       [11,  0,  0, 12, 12, 12]], dtype=int32)

In [8]: s2 = nd.generate_binary_structure(2,2)

In [9]: for l in range(1, nlab+1):
   ...:     is_l = lab==l
   ...:     if np.sum(is_l) ==1:
   ...:         continue
   ...:     is_l_padded = nd.binary_dilation(is_l, s2)
   ...:     border = np.logical_xor( is_l_padded, is_l)
   ...:     num_ones = mat[border].sum()
   ...:     print("label %d has %d ones around it" % (l, num_ones))
   ...: 
label 1 has 2 ones around it
label 2 has 1 ones around it
label 3 has 5 ones around it
label 6 has 5 ones around it
label 7 has 6 ones around it
label 12 has 2 ones around it
```